# Complete set coset representatives of a subgroup $H$ in a group $G$

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, symmetric-groups, latin-square

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be a finite subgroup of index $n$ in $G$. Is there any systematic way of finding a complete set of coset representatives(That is a set of coset representatives for all conjugates of $H$ in $G$) for $H$ in $G$?

I have a group $G$ of order 24 inside $S_6$ and a subgroup $H$ of order 4 inside $G$ whose conjugacy class of subgroups has 3 elements. I want to find a complete set of coset representatives for it. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Generally, the way for computing all the (right) cosets of a (finite) group $G$ is as follows:

> To compute all the right costs of a subgroup $H$ in a finite group $G$, first write $H$, then choose any $a \in G$ such that $a \notin H$, and compute $Ha$. Next, choose any $b \in G$ such that $b \notin H \cup Ha$, and compute $Hb$. Continue in this way until all elements of $G$ have been exhausted.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I need a set of coset representatives that works for all conjugates of $H$ in G. Not $H$ alone.

Comment: Hello, @Anupam Ah. See whether [Question 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2254/if-two-subgroups-have-a-complete-set-of-left-coset-representatives-in-common-th) and [Question 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331126/construct-a-complete-system-of-representatives-for-the-left-cosets-of-h-2-in) are useful.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will look at it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not true in general that there exists a single set of size $n$ that forms a complete set of (right) coset representatives for $g^{-1}Hg$ in $G$ for all $g \in G$. For example this is not possible in a subgroup $H$ of order $2$ in $G = A_4$.